# bootstrap css source or local android glyphicon difference

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

on android mobile (4.4 note3...shouldnt matter) I made a small html site referencing the bootstrap stylesheet in the head, then in the body I reference the phone glyphicon in a span via a copy/paste from the example on the bootstrap getting started site.

problem is, if I reference bootstrap stylesheet(not theme, not js) via the CDN then the phone icon shows up as expected. if I navigate to http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css in a browser I can copy the bootstrap source...then I can make a local stylesheet from that source and reference it in the site instead of linking to the CDN stylesheet...though whenever I do this, the phone icon breaks.

to be clear, identical source for bootstrap css, one is from the recommended CDN - that works fine. the other, a copy paste from the recommended CDN but stored locally - that ones broken.

Please explain, what could possibly be the difference (I even went and changed my user agent in my computers browser to android and tried copy paste that code though it shouldnt have mattered - in case it served browser specific css...it doesnt - duh, its just a css file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely because the stylesheet uses a relative reference to the glyphicon font inside a font folder that is not located on your local computer.  Download the distribution files for Bootstrap here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ and copy the fonts folder into your project at the same level as the folder where your css file is saved.